# How to adjust >> and << behavior in Emacs (Vim emulation, indent, dedent)?

Tags: emacs, formatting

In Vim emulation mode (viper + vimpulse) << and >> are working similarly to Vim's. I would just like them to indent with 2 spaces. How do I do that? (I know, trivial. But useful)

Comment: No offence, but considering this is your second make emacs act like vim post. Maybe you should just use vim?

Comment: @J.J. I'm switching from Vim right now. Sorry for basic questions, I just try to retain previous level of productivity or minimize the drop, and hope for enormous gains in the future.

Comment: As a general rule asking "how do I make Y emulate X's feature Z?" should probably be accompanied by an explanation of what feature Z does...

Comment: @phjr: thanks for the explanation. I am used to people being Holistic about their editors. The flame wars of "Vi(m) VS Emacs" come to mind. Judging by your comment; you have deemed some feature of emacs worth the effort of switching. May I enquire what that is?

Comment: @J.J. Almost unlimited scriptability. Even now I feel I'm more in control using Emacs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading viper-cmd.el code (and testing), I determined that correct answer is:

```
(setq viper-shift-width 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that mode probably uses Emacs' `tab-width` or `c-basic-offset` settings. Both can be set with:

```
(setq tab-width 4)
(setq c-basic-offset 4)
```

(Of course, use whatever size you want in place of `4`.)

Answer (score 0):

In order to have space and not tab, add this to your .emacs :

```
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
```

To have Emacs indent with 2 spaces, do like mipadi told you, but I would use `default-tab-width`

```
(setq default-tab-width 2)
```